# Why does Javascript not work on my Samsung Internet Browser? Using Samsung Galaxy S7

Tags: javascript, android, html

I'm using no-ip.com free domain and the site loads fine on my Samsung S7 when using Chrome, yet when I try using Javascript with Samsung Internet browser which is the preinstalled browser for my phone, the calculations don't work.

Here is my Javascript and HTML code:

```js
function Run1() {

//METRIC TO METRIC
          var SpecialValue = 0;
if (document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value == 1000000000000000000000000)
    {
       
SpecialValue = document.getElementById("Input1").value * document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value / document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value;
      document.getElementById("Input2").value = SpecialValue;
    }
else if (document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value == 1000000000000000000000)
    {
        
SpecialValue = document.getElementById("Input1").value * document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value / document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value;
      document.getElementById("Input2").value = SpecialValue;
    }
else if (document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value == 1000000000000000000)
    {
        
 SpecialValue = document.getElementById("Input1").value * document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value / document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value;
      document.getElementById("Input2").value = SpecialValue;
    }
else if (document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value == 1000000000000000)
    {
        
 SpecialValue = document.getElementById("Input1").value * document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value / document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value;
      document.getElementById("Input2").value = SpecialValue;
    }
else if (document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value == 1000000000000)
    {
        
 SpecialValue = document.getElementById("Input1").value * document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value / document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value;
      document.getElementById("Input2").value = SpecialValue;
    }
else if (document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value == 1000000000)
    {
        
 SpecialValue = document.getElementById("Input1").value * document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value / document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value;
      document.getElementById("Input2").value = SpecialValue;
    }
else if (document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value == 1000000)
    {
        
 SpecialValue = document.getElementById("Input1").value * document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value / document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value;
      document.getElementById("Input2").value = SpecialValue;
    }     
else if (document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value == 1000)
    {
        
 SpecialValue = document.getElementById("Input1").value * document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value / document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value;
      document.getElementById("Input2").value = SpecialValue;
    }     
else if (document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value == 100)
    {
         SpecialValue = document.getElementById("Input1").value * document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value / document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value;
      document.getElementById("Input2").value = SpecialValue;
    }
else if (document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value == 10)
    {
        
 SpecialValue = document.getElementById("Input1").value * document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value / document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value;
      document.getElementById("Input2").value = SpecialValue;
    }
else if (document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value == 1)
    {
        
 SpecialValue = document.getElementById("Input1").value * document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value / document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value;
      document.getElementById("Input2").value = SpecialValue;
    }

else if (document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value == .1)
    {
        
 SpecialValue = document.getElementById("Input1").value * document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value / document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value;
      document.getElementById("Input2").value = SpecialValue;
    }
   else if (document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value == .01)
    {
        
 SpecialValue = document.getElementById("Input1").value * document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value / document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value;
      document.getElementById("Input2").value = SpecialValue;
    }
        else if (document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value == .001)
    {
        
 SpecialValue = document.getElementById("Input1").value * document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value / document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value;
      document.getElementById("Input2").value = SpecialValue;
    }
        else if (document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value == .000001)
    {
        
 SpecialValue = document.getElementById("Input1").value * document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value / document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value;
      document.getElementById("Input2").value = SpecialValue;
    }
        else if (document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value == .000000001)
    {
        
 SpecialValue = document.getElementById("Input1").value * document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value / document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value;
      document.getElementById("Input2").value = SpecialValue;
    }
        else if (document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value == .000000000001)
    {
        
 SpecialValue = document.getElementById("Input1").value * document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value / document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value;
      document.getElementById("Input2").value = SpecialValue;
    }
        else if (document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value == .000000000000001)
    {
        
 SpecialValue = document.getElementById("Input1").value * document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value / document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value;
      document.getElementById("Input2").value = SpecialValue;
    }
        else if (document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value == .000000000000000001)
    {
        
 SpecialValue = document.getElementById("Input1").value * document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value / document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value;
      document.getElementById("Input2").value = SpecialValue;
    }
        else if (document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value == .000000000000000000001)
    {
        
 SpecialValue = document.getElementById("Input1").value * document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value / document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value;
      document.getElementById("Input2").value = SpecialValue;
    }
else if (document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value == 1.0E-24)
    {
        
 SpecialValue = document.getElementById("Input1").value * document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value / document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value;
      document.getElementById("Input2").value = SpecialValue;
    }
    
else if (document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value == .0254)
    {
        
 SpecialValue = document.getElementById("Input1").value * document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value / document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value;
     
      document.getElementById("Input2").value = SpecialValue;
    }
    
else if (document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value == .3048)
    {
        
 SpecialValue = document.getElementById("Input1").value * document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value / document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value;
 
      document.getElementById("Input2").value = SpecialValue;
    }
    
else if (document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value == .9144)
    {
        
 SpecialValue = document.getElementById("Input1").value * document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value / document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value;
      document.getElementById("Input2").value = SpecialValue;
    }
    
else if (document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value == 1609.344)
    {
        
 SpecialValue = document.getElementById("Input1").value * document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value / document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value;
      document.getElementById("Input2").value = SpecialValue;
    }

    else if (document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value == 1852)
    {
        
 SpecialValue = document.getElementById("Input1").value * document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value / document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value;
      document.getElementById("Input2").value = SpecialValue;
    }
    
}


function Run2() {




//METRIC TO METRIC INPUT 2

if (document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value == 1000000000000000000000000)
    {
        
 SpecialValue = document.getElementById("Input2").value * document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value / document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value;
      document.getElementById("Input1").value = SpecialValue;
    }
else if (document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value == 1000000000000000000000)
    {
        
 SpecialValue = document.getElementById("Input2").value * document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value / document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value;
      document.getElementById("Input1").value = SpecialValue;
    }
else if (document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value == 1000000000000000000)
    {
        
 SpecialValue = document.getElementById("Input2").value * document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value / document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value;
      document.getElementById("Input1").value = SpecialValue;
    }
else if (document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value == 1000000000000000)
    {
        
 SpecialValue = document.getElementById("Input2").value * document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value / document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value;
      document.getElementById("Input1").value = SpecialValue;
    }
else if (document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value == 1000000000000)
    {
        
 SpecialValue = document.getElementById("Input2").value * document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value / document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value;
      document.getElementById("Input1").value = SpecialValue;
    }
else if (document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value == 1000000000)
    {
        
 SpecialValue = document.getElementById("Input2").value * document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value / document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value;
      document.getElementById("Input1").value = SpecialValue;
    }
else if (document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value == 1000000)
    {
        
 SpecialValue = document.getElementById("Input2").value * document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value / document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value;
      document.getElementById("Input1").value = SpecialValue;
    }     
else if (document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value == 1000)
    {
        
 SpecialValue = document.getElementById("Input2").value * document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value / document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value;
      document.getElementById("Input1").value = SpecialValue;
    }     
else if (document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value == 100)
    {
         SpecialValue = document.getElementById("Input2").value * document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value / document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value;
      document.getElementById("Input1").value = SpecialValue;
    }
else if (document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value == 10)
    {
        
 SpecialValue = document.getElementById("Input2").value * document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value / document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value;
      document.getElementById("Input1").value = SpecialValue;
    }
else if (document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value == 1)
    {
        
 SpecialValue = document.getElementById("Input2").value * document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value / document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value;
      document.getElementById("Input1").value = SpecialValue;
    }

else if (document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value == .1)
    {
        
 SpecialValue = document.getElementById("Input2").value * document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value / document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value;
      document.getElementById("Input1").value = SpecialValue;
    }
   else if (document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value == .01)
    {
        
 SpecialValue = document.getElementById("Input2").value * document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value / document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value;
      document.getElementById("Input1").value = SpecialValue;
    }
        else if (document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value == .001)
    {
        
 SpecialValue = document.getElementById("Input2").value * document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value / document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value;
      document.getElementById("Input1").value = SpecialValue;
    }
        else if (document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value == .000001)
    {
        
 SpecialValue = document.getElementById("Input2").value * document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value / document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value;
      document.getElementById("Input1").value = SpecialValue;
    }
        else if (document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value == .000000001)
    {
        
 SpecialValue = document.getElementById("Input2").value * document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value / document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value;
      document.getElementById("Input1").value = SpecialValue;
    }
        else if (document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value == .000000000001)
    {
        
 SpecialValue = document.getElementById("Input2").value * document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value / document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value;
      document.getElementById("Input1").value = SpecialValue;
    }
        else if (document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value == .000000000000001)
    {
        
 SpecialValue = document.getElementById("Input2").value * document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value / document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value;
      document.getElementById("Input1").value = SpecialValue;
    }
        else if (document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value == .000000000000000001)
    {
        
 SpecialValue = document.getElementById("Input2").value * document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value / document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value;
      document.getElementById("Input1").value = SpecialValue;
    }
        else if (document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value == .000000000000000000001)
    {
        
 SpecialValue = document.getElementById("Input2").value * document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value / document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value;
      document.getElementById("Input1").value = SpecialValue;
    }
else if (document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value == .000000000000000000000001)
    {
        
 SpecialValue = document.getElementById("Input2").value * document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value / document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value;
      document.getElementById("Input1").value = SpecialValue;
    }
    
else if (document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value == .0254)
    {
        
 SpecialValue = document.getElementById("Input2").value * document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value / document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value;
   
      document.getElementById("Input1").value = SpecialValue;
    }

    else if (document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value == .3048)
    {
        
 SpecialValue = document.getElementById("Input2").value * document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value / document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value;

      document.getElementById("Input1").value = SpecialValue;
    }
    
else if (document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value == 0.9144)
    {
        
 SpecialValue = document.getElementById("Input2").value * document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value / document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value;
      document.getElementById("Input1").value = SpecialValue;
    }    
    
else if (document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value == 1609.344)
    {
        
 SpecialValue = document.getElementById("Input2").value * document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value / document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value;
      document.getElementById("Input1").value = SpecialValue;
    }    
    
else if (document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value == 1852)
    {
        
 SpecialValue = document.getElementById("Input2").value * document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value / document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value;
      document.getElementById("Input1").value = SpecialValue;
    }    
        
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

      <title>Converter</title> 
    
</head>
<body>
   
    
    
   
    <p>From:</p>  
    <select id="MetricAndImperial1" class="js-example-basic-single" onchange="Run2()">
        <option value="0.0254">Inches</option>
        <option value="0.3048">Feet</option>
        <option value="0.9144">Yards</option>
        <option value="1609.344">Miles</option>
        <option value="1852">Nautical Miles</option>
        <option value="1000000000000000000000000">Yottameter</option>
        <option value="1000000000000000000000">Zettameter</option>
        <option value="1000000000000000000">Exameter</option>
        <option value="1000000000000000">Petameter</option>
        <option value="1000000000000">Terameter</option>
        <option value="1000000000">Gigameter</option>
        <option value="1000000">Megameter</option>
        <option value="1000">Kilometer</option>
        <option value="100">Hectometer</option>
        <option value="10">Decameter</option>
        <option value="1">Meter</option>
        <option value=".1">Decimeter</option>
        <option value=".01">Centimeter</option>
        <option value=".001">Millimeter</option>
        <option value=".000001">Micrometer</option>
        <option value=".000000001">Nanometer</option>
        <option value=".000000000001">Picometer</option>
        <option value=".000000000000001">Femtometer</option>
        <option value=".000000000000000001">Attometer</option>
        <option value=".000000000000000000001">Zeptometer</option>
        <option value=".000000000000000000000001">Yoctometer</option>
        <option value="198">Rods</option>
        <option value="7920.02">Furlongs</option>
        <option value="4">Hands</option>
        <option value="72">Fathoms</option>
        <option value="218740">Leagues</option>
    </select>
        
  

<input style="height:50%;font-size:60pt;width:1000px;" id="Input1" type="number" oninput="Run1()" onchange="Run1()" />

        <p>To:</p>
        
  <select id="MetricAndImperial2" class="js-example-basic-single" onchange="Run1()">
        <option value="0.0254">Inches</option>
        <option value="0.3048">Feet</option>
        <option value="0.9144">Yards</option>
        <option value="1609.344">Miles</option>
        <option value="1852">Nautical Miles</option>
        <option value="1000000000000000000000000">Yottameter</option>
        <option value="1000000000000000000000">Zettameter</option>
        <option value="1000000000000000000">Exameter</option>
        <option value="1000000000000000">Petameter</option>
        <option value="1000000000000">Terameter</option>
        <option value="1000000000">Gigameter</option>
        <option value="1000000">Megameter</option>
        <option value="1000">Kilometer</option>
        <option value="100">Hectometer</option>
        <option value="10">Decameter</option>
        <option value="1">Meter</option>
        <option value=".1">Decimeter</option>
        <option value=".01">Centimeter</option>
        <option value=".001">Millimeter</option>
        <option value=".000001">Micrometer</option>
        <option value=".000000001">Nanometer</option>
        <option value=".000000000001">Picometer</option>
        <option value=".000000000000001">Femtometer</option>
        <option value=".000000000000000001">Attometer</option>
        <option value=".000000000000000000001">Zeptometer</option>
        <option value=".000000000000000000000001">Yoctometer</option>
        <option value="198">Rods</option>
        <option value="7920.02">Furlongs</option>
        <option value="4">Hands</option>
        <option value="72">Fathoms</option>
        <option value="218740">Leagues</option>
    </select>

    <input style="height:50%;font-size:60pt;width:1000px;" id="Input2" type="number" oninput="Run2()" onchange="Run2()" />
        
    
    
  <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript" src="PrototypeMath.js"></script>
  
      <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  
      <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
   
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".js-example-basic-single").select2();
});
</script>
    </body>
```

Please help. Thank you. I dont' know why I have to add details to post this but whatever.

Answer (score 0):

No offense. But Samsung is not a major web browser maker. Consider using CHrome, Firefox, Opera, etc. and you will become a happier person.

IMHO, Samsung is supposed to focus on the hardware and customizing the OS and apps in their phones. Working in the web, we are encountering so many issues that only happen in the Samsung Browser. Though it is based on Chromium, it does not behave like Chromium.

Try seeing if you can connect the phone to a computer and inspect the web browser to see if you have any errors in the page. That might help.

Answer (score 0):

Changed to CDN and it works now.